# Get values from JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json

Using an API token, I get the following JSON:

```
   {"data": [
            {"person_id": {
                "name": "AAA",
                "email": [;
                  {
                    "label": "work",
                    "value": "aaa@xxxcompany.cpm",
                    "primary": true
                  }
                ],
                "phone": [
                  {
                    "label": "work",
                    "value": "05078945623",
                    "primary": true
                  }
                ]
              }
    }
```

I tried the following codes but it didn;t work

```
foreach ($object['data'] as $key => $value){

     echo $value['person_id']['email']['value'];
     echo $value['person_id']['phone']['value'];
}
```

How to get the email value: aaa@xxxcompany.com and phone value: 0507894562 in PHP?

I got the error:

> Notice: Undefined index: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\pipedrive\index.php
>   on line 44
>
> Notice: Undefined index: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\pipedrive\index.php
>   on line 45

Comment: email is an array, try ['email'][0]['value']

Comment: Invalid JSON: missing closing `]}` and what's up with the semi-colon `"email": [;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow the notation down the tree:

```
foo =  { "data": [
 |         |     |    { "person_id":
 |         |     |          |        {
 |         |     |          |          "name": "AAA",
 |         |     |          |          "email":   [
 |         |     |          |          |          |    { "label": "work"
 |         |     |          |          |          |         |
 |         |     |          |          |          |         |
foo    ['data']  [0]  ['person_id']    ['email']  [0]  ['label']
```

So

```
 JS:    foo.data[0].person_id.email[0].label        -> "work"
 PHP:   $foo->data[0]->person_id->email[0]->label   -> "work"
```

You forgot all of the arrays (`[]`) in there, and only handled the objects (`{}`).

Comment: well, I'm writing it as JS, so... not really? But yeah, probably should put in a PHP equivalent.

Comment: like the way you described this

Comment: damn, i'm new to JSON, didn't know exactly how this works but your answer really helped a lot. Thank you so much :)

Comment: json is just javascript. literally. it's essentially a cut&paste of the right-hand side of a JS variable assignment. That's it. it can't represent "code", just "data", but otherwise it's completely and utterly "javascript".